# How is Wordpress' 'sizes' attribute, for images, computed?

Tags: css, wordpress, image, alignment, resolution

Not sure if this started happening very recently, or if this has been an issue for longer, but I feel it's the former. I think I would have noticed, otherwise.

When I add an image to my post, and set the size to 'enlarged' or 'full' (presumably, I'm translating this from Portuguese), my (custom) theme shows these images either enlarged, or in full width. (To allow for this, I added add_theme_support('align-wide') to my functions.php.)

However, the file that is used, on larger screens, is not the correct one.

This is the image tag I get when including an image that is set to have full width:

```
<img loading="lazy" width="1003" height="564" src="[...]image.jpg?resize=640%2C360&amp;ssl=1" alt="" class="wp-image-115865 shadow" srcset="[...]image.jpg?w=1920&amp;ssl=1 1920w, [...]image.jpg?resize=300%2C169&amp;ssl=1 300w, [...]image.jpg?resize=1024%2C576&amp;ssl=1 1024w, [...]image.jpg?resize=1536%2C864&amp;ssl=1 1536w, [...]image.jpg?resize=640%2C360&amp;ssl=1 640w, [...]image.jpg?resize=1320%2C743&amp;ssl=1 1320w, [...]image.jpg?resize=150%2C84&amp;ssl=1 150w" sizes="(max-width: 640px) 100vw, 640px">
```

You can see that the image is displayed at 1003x564 pixels, but that the 'sizes' attribute sets a max-width at 640 pixels.
As a result, this image, displayed at 1003x564 pixels, is an upscaled image of 640 pixels wide.

The result is pixelated, which is not pretty.

What is defining the 'sizes' attribute? Why is it, here, set to 640 pixels? Can I change this? How?

Answer (score 1):

The function that adds attr in images is [wp_get_attachment_image()](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/1020306fe96172a74532378bf1d4e79da67e8b4b/wp-includes/media.php#L1026)

The function that adds size attr in images is [wp_calculate_image_sizes()](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/1020306fe96172a74532378bf1d4e79da67e8b4b/wp-includes/media.php#L1660)

They have given filter `wp_calculate_image_sizes` to modify as per your need.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'm aware of this. But, that doesn't explain why the maximum size is set to 640 pixels, as opposed to something closer to the maximum size of the image in question. Either way, yeah, I suppose I have to use this to adjust the 'sizes' attribute.